# How to get Impala v2.5 set options live_progress and live_summary to work

Tags: hadoop, impala

I've tried to do this many times and failed every time - there's just not much information on Impala out there.

Trying to set a live progress or live summary query option in Impala shell - the command appears to work, although no confirmation displays after executing:

`set live_progress=true;`
`set live_summary=true;`

Could be a permissions issue - I am not familiar with how to troubleshoot this though. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `--live-progress` or `--live_summary` options when you start impala-shell to see if it works.

```
$ impala-shell -i <impalad-host:port> -d <database> --live_progress
```

Comment: cool idea! I ended up adding it to the query file and ran on a larger query - apparently they don't work on small queries -- I was just running a select x limit 10 type of query, which worked.